# Gradient of a line integral of a vector field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, vector-fields, berry-pancharatnam-phase, aharonov-bohm

I need some advice on how to perform the gradient of a line integral of a vector field.

My problem refers to the Aharonov-Bohm Effect as it is discussed in the QM book from David Griffiths, as it follows in the image linked here $\rightarrow$ https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYrxp.jpg

I don't uderstand how the gradient (nabla operator in $R$) is acting on the integral in g.

Comment: A limit integral has as its argument the limits. $\int_{a}^b f(x)dx$ is a function of $a$ and $b$ only. $x$ is an integration dummy variable. Two dimensional domain. You can take operators of it. $g(\int f(x)~dx)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever wrote that is either being *very* loose and unusual with notation or misstating what’s happening. It is true that the derivative of $f(x-y)$ w.r.t. the argument is the negative of the derivative w.r.t. a variable in summation ($x-y$ being a summation):

$$f’(x-y) \equiv \frac{df(x-y)}{d(x-y)} $$ $$ \implies  f’(x-y) = - \frac{\partial f(x-y)}{\partial y}$$

While that’s correct (and hence the parenthetical statement “$\nabla_R =  -\nabla$ when acting on a function of $r-R$” is also correct), that is not what’s happening here. $g= \int_{R}^r A(r’) \cdot dr’$ is not a function of $r-R$.

What’s happening is just that taking the derivative of a limit integral wrt a limit is simply the function at the value of the limit for the upper limit, and is the inverse of that for the lower limit:

$$\frac{\partial (\int_{a}^b f(x)dx)}{\partial a}=-f(a)$$

---

It’s not clear what mean with $\nabla_R =-\nabla$. It could be saying $$\nabla_R g(r-R) = -\nabla_{(r-R)} g(r-R)$$ where the RHS is w.r.t. to the argument, usually just written $\nabla \cdot g$.

Or it could also mean $$\nabla_R g(r-R) =-\nabla_r g(r-R) $$

Because both are true. But again, **that is not the explanation** for the relationship giving $\nabla_R \cdot (\int_{R}^r A) = -A(R)$. The explanation is the derivative of a limit integral, technically from the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 0):

It is the fundamental theorem of calculus just flip the integral limits and then the derivative of an integral gives the function evaluated at R.